# error Unsupported operation: read-only.how remove items from list if I use sqlite flutter and show the names in future builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, android-sqlite

[image]
this code show me the names of Sqlite database before begin the game I want to add the players names from database to can save the records so I use `check box` to select the `team1` players and save the names in list `team1` then after team1 have two  names, I want to enter the `team2` list players without include the team1 players by `Setstate` and `removewhere`

```
         FutureBuilder(
          future: readdata,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              allplayer = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: allplayer.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                  return enable == true
                      ? Card(
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(allplayer[i]['name']),
                            value: checks[i],
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (value == true) {
                                  team1.addAll([allplayer[i]['name']]);

                                  if (team1.length >= 2) {
                                    allplayer.removeWhere((element) =>
                                        element['name'] == team1[0]);
                                    allplayer.removeWhere((element) =>
                                        element['name'] == team1[1]);
                                    teamname = 'team 2';
                                    enable = false;
                                  }
                                } else if (value == false) {
                                  team1.removeWhere((element) =>
                                      element == allplayer[i]['name']);
                                }
                                checks[i] = value!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      : Card(
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(allplayer[i]['name']),
                            value: checks[i],
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (value == true) {
                                  team2.addAll([allplayer[i]['name']]);
                                } else if (value == false) {
                                  team2.removeWhere((element) =>
                                      element == allplayer[i]['name']);
                                }

                                checks[i] = value!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                },
              );
            }
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make one more variable in column as teamName when user select the team then update that varable as teamname and also check when selecting name is not listed in any team then he can add

Comment: by default the first screen is to add the team1 players names, after the user select two name I  review the players names again to add team2, but my problem is I want review names without team1 names. I do not know if you understand me

Comment: I think the answer at the second `card` at `title: Text(allplayer[i]['name'])` but I do not know how review the `allplayer` list without `team1` names